# Video Processor MFT (Media Foundation) missing under Windows 7 Pro 64bit

Tags: windows, installation, ms-media-foundation

I want to use the "Video Processor MFT" of the Media Foundation transforms and I'm using Windows 7 Pro SP1 64bit. But this MFT is missing on my system VS2013 en VS2015RC installed. 
On a Windows 8.1 system it's there and I read at some places that it should work under Windows 7. Does someone know how to get this MFT at my system? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: ["While the documentation does not explicitly say so, the MFT appears to only be available starting with Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162913)

Comment: Thanks now it's clear. From here [link](http://de.binarydb.com/file/msvproc.dll-v380604.html) it looked it's supported but I doubted whether the information was correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Class not registered" when loading the Video Processor MFT on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140795/class-not-registered-when-loading-the-video-processor-mft-on-windows-7)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but at this moment I'm not busy any more with this project.