# "Class not registered" when loading the Video Processor MFT on Windows 7

Tags: winapi, dll, com, windows-7, ms-media-foundation

I have the following COM call:

```
IMFTransform* pMFT = NULL;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoProcessorMFT, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMFT));
```

On my development machine, this call to `CoCreateInstance` succeeds.
However, when I deploy this on my old Windows 7 machine,
the call to `CoCreateInstance` fails,
and I don't know why.
Here's how I'm displaying the error:

```
_com_error err(hr);
LPCTSTR hrErrMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
WCHAR msg[MAX_PATH];
StringCbPrintf(msg, sizeof(msg), L"HRESULT=0x%X, %s", errContext, hrErr, hrErrMsg);
MessageBox(hwnd, msg, L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
```

And here's the error I get in that message box:

```
HRESULT=0x80040154, Class not registered
```

That is, the COM class for [the Video Processor MFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/video-processor-mft)
is not registered.
I see that `CLSID_VideoProcessorMFT` is defined as:

```
EXTERN_GUID(CLSID_VideoProcessorMFT, 0x88753b26, 0x5b24, 0x49bd, 0xb2, 0xe7, 0xc, 0x44, 0x5c, 0x78, 0xc9, 0x82);
```

This is the GUID `88753B26-5B24-49bd-B2E7-0C445C78C982` in disguise.
I understand that COM classes are registered in the Windows Registry with a key containing this GUID.
Using Registry Editor on my developer machine, I can see the key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{88753B26-5B24-49bd-B2E7-0C445C78C982}
```

and this key has a "Default" value of `%SystemRoot%\System32\msvproc.dll`,
referring to the filepath `C:\Windows\System32\msvproc.dll`,
which does exist.

On my old Windows 7 machine, this key in the registry does not exist --
as expected, given the "Class not registered" error.
And there is no file at `C:\Windows\System32\msvproc.dll`.
But this is where the trail goes cold.
I don't know what is supposed to register that class in the registry,
and why it hasn't run on my old Windows 7 machine.

Possible conclusions:

- I have to register the Video Processor MFT myself.
  However, the docs do not suggest this,
  and I don't know how I would do it.
- Windows 7 does not support the Video Processor MFT.
  But the docs provide no indication of this.
  Indeed, they say "Media Foundation requires Windows Vista or later",
  which should include my Windows 7 machine.
- I'm loading the Video Processor MFT in the wrong way.
  Is there a more system-independent way to load it?

**Which of these is the right conclusion? Is it possible to load the Video Processor MFT on Windows 7? If so, how?**

Comment: The MFT could be missing in Windows 7. Or require [Platform Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2670838/platform-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1). Current documentation already does not mention this, but this MFT is definitely not here from the first days of Media Foundation.

Comment: Hello again @RomanR. :-) Thanks for the info! For reference, the terrible old Windows laptop is on Windows 7, Service Pack 1, which is apparently the latest Service Pack. I wasn't aware of the concept of a Platform Update - I'll try that and report back. Otherwise, I'll just live with the lack of Windows 7 support for now. (It would be lovely if Microsoft documented which versions introduced support for their APIs ...)

Comment: From mfidl.h, CLSID_VideoProcessorMFT is only defined for _WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE and higher, which is Windows 8.1, if you set your winver stuff correctly, you shouldn't even be able to compile: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=vs-2019

Comment: See also comments here: [Video Processor MFT (Media Foundation) missing under Windows 7 Pro 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036950/video-processor-mft-media-foundation-missing-under-windows-7-pro-64bit)

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks, I learned several new things from this comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though even [older documentation for Video Processor MFT](https://web.archive.org/web/20120609055041/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162913(v=vs.85).aspx) does not mention availability restrictions, they can still be assumed from [related content](https://web.archive.org/web/20120614113626/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448069(v=vs.85).aspx):

> #### Requirements
>
> Minimum supported client: Windows 8 Release Preview
>
> Minimum supported server: Windows Server 2012

Applications that target earlier versions of Windows are likely to be supposed to use [other DSPs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/windowsmediadigitalsignalprocessors) like Color Control Transform DSP and Color Converter DSP. These were/are not GPU accelerated though.

The advantage of Video Processor MFT was that it supported GPU-accelerated video processing using Microsoft Direct3D 11.

Comment: Thanks Roman! That seems clear, especially in combination with @SimonMourier's comment. I'll give up on Windows 7 support for now ...

Answer (score 1):

(This is an expansion on @SimonMourier's very helpful comment, for future readers, since it was all new to me.)

I believe `CLSID_VideoProcessorMFT` is available as follows:

- For "Windows Desktop Applications" on >= Windows 8.1
- For "Windows Store Applications" on >= Windows 10
- For "Windows Phone Applications" on >= Windows 10

The header file `mfidl.h` documents which Windows version a specific COM class was introduced in. Following `CLSID_VideoProcessorMFT` to its definition, I find:

```
#if (WINVER >= _WIN32_WINNT_WINTHRESHOLD) 
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)
// ...
EXTERN_GUID(CLSID_VideoProcessorMFT, 0x88753b26, 0x5b24, 0x49bd, 0xb2, 0xe7, 0xc, 0x44, 0x5c, 0x78, 0xc9, 0x82);
#endif /* WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP) */
#endif // (WINVER >= _WIN32_WINNT_WINTHRESHOLD) 
// ...
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)
#if (WINVER >= _WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE) 
#if (WINVER < _WIN32_WINNT_WINTHRESHOLD) 
EXTERN_GUID(CLSID_VideoProcessorMFT, 0x88753b26, 0x5b24, 0x49bd, 0xb2, 0xe7, 0xc, 0x44, 0x5c, 0x78, 0xc9, 0x82);
#endif // (WINVER < _WIN32_WINNT_WINTHRESHOLD) 
#endif // (WINVER >= _WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE) 
// ...
#endif /* WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP) */
```

By following and decoding all these macros, I got the availability list above.